# How do I get an openGL texture out of a video using AVFoundation?

Tags: cocoa, opengl, avfoundation, qtkit

Building a 64bit native OSX (not iOS) ap targeting 10.7+. Somewhat new to dealing with video files in a Cocoa universe.

I would like to be able to open a video file and display the output inside an openGL render (IE, I would like to be able to efficiently access the framebuffer of a video and turn each frame into an opengl texture.)

Conceptually this seems straightforward, but I'm having a difficult time wading through various (old and deprecated)examples and options, all of which seem to have been recently deprecated in favor of AVFoundation. It's possible I missed something, but examples of using AVFoundation with OpenGL seem thin on the ground.

To clarify a bit further, [this sample application (QTCoreVideo101 from Apple)](http://genekc07.stowers.org/Users/mec/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#samplecode/QTCoreVideo101/Introduction/Intro.html) does more or less exactly what I want, except that it is built around the deprecated QTKit will therefore not even compile in 64 bit.

I am reading through the AVFoundation docs right now, but I'm still not sure it make sense to try and get a glTexture out of AVFoundation or if I should be looking elsewhere.

## **UPDATE**

This is the solution I ended up going with. "thisLayer.layerSource.videoPlayerOutput" is AVPlayerItemVideoOutput object.

```
if ([thisLayer.layerSource.videoPlayerOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:playerTime]){

    frameBuffer= [thisLayer.layerSource.videoPlayerOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:playerTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];

    CVReturn result= CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(NULL,
                                           textureCache,
                                           frameBuffer,
                                           NULL,
                                           &textureRef);
    if(result == kCVReturnSuccess){
            // These appear to be GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB
            thisLayer.layerSource.vid_glTextureTarget=CVOpenGLTextureGetTarget(textureRef);
            thisLayer.layerSource.vid_glTexture=CVOpenGLTextureGetName(textureRef);
            thisLayer.layerSource.vid_glTextureSize=NSMakeSize(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(frameBuffer), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(frameBuffer));
            thisLayer.layerSource.vid_ciimage=[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:frameBuffer];
            CFRelease(textureRef);
            CVOpenGLTextureCacheFlush(textureCache, 0);
    }else{
            NSLog(@"INTERNAL ERROR FAILED WITH CODE: %i",result);
    }
    CVBufferRelease(frameBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` (added to your `AVAssetReader`) will output a `CVPixelBufferRef`, of which you can specify your preferred format to upload to OpenGL via `glTexImage` or `glTexSubImage`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this too, this is my current solution:

```
- (BOOL) renderWithCVPixelBufferForTime: (NSTimeInterval) time
{
    CMTime vTime = [self.playeroutput itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];

    if ([self.playeroutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime]) {
        if (_cvPixelBufferRef) {
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_cvPixelBufferRef, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
            CVPixelBufferRelease(_cvPixelBufferRef);
        }
        _cvPixelBufferRef = [self.playeroutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_cvPixelBufferRef, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
        GLsizei       texWidth    = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(_cvPixelBufferRef);
        GLsizei       texHeight   = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(_cvPixelBufferRef);
        GLvoid *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_cvPixelBufferRef);


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, self.textureName);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_STORAGE_HINT_APPLE , GL_STORAGE_CACHED_APPLE);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGB, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE, baseAddress);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0);
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there isn't a more efficient solution, I also have a question on the same topic with several approaches:

[Best path from AVPlayerItemVideoOutput to openGL Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24933453/2754888)

The lock base address call is a hog, I'm not sure it's truly required.

Comment: Nice... I ended up doing something similar (using the pixelbuffer and putting it into a texturecache). I haven't actually tried profiling your code vs mine so I'm not sure what's faster, but I will post the code in another answer in a moment (too long for a comment). I did not do any locking - maybe I should have, but worked fine in a production environment for a while, running several HD videos at once even.